# How to display an random items from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

```
var items    = ['imgs/garbagebag.svg', //[0]
               'imgs/straw.svg', // [1]
               'imgs/utensil.svg', // [2]
               'imgs/chipbag.svg', // [3]
               'imgs/eggs.svg', // [4]


               'imgs/glasscup.svg', //[5]
               'imgs/ketchupbottle.svg', //[6]
               'imgs/jamjar.svg', //[7]
               'imgs/milkbottle.svg', //[8]
               'imgs/popbottle.svg', //[9]


               'imgs/eggshell.svg', //[10]
               'imgs/apple.svg', //[11]
               'imgs/banana.svg', //[12]
               'imgs/teabag.svg', // [13]
               'imgs/leave.svg', // [14]


              'imgs/jug.svg', // [15]
              'imgs/tetrapak.svg', // [16]
              'imgs/container.svg', // [17]
              'imgs/plasticbottle.svg', // [18]
              'imgs/can.svg', //[19]

              'imgs/newspaper.svg', //[20]
              'imgs/cerealbox.svg', // [21]
              'imgs/book.svg', // [22]
              'imgs/cardboard.svg', // [23]
              'imgs/bag.svg' // [24]
]
// This is the black hole on the wall
var hole = document.getElementById("hole");
// starts functioning after 5 seconds
var start = setInterval(shuffle,5000);
// displays an random items from array one by one
function shuffle(){
    hole.addEventListener("click",function(){
    console.log("items");
    items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)] 
});
}
```

[image]

Hi, so this is a mini-game that teaches users how to recycle. In the screenshot, users are required to click the black gap/hole in order to display the random items one by one inside the black hole (I tried appending it but I don't know what I should create before). I am befuddled on how to achieve this. What I have doesn't seem to be enough. I appreciate solutions and tips. Thank you for reading my post.

[image]

**UPDATE:** So the codes Elliot provided is working. But for some reasons, newly created + randomized images have no pixels! I tried assigning new width and height + z-index with className in css but that is not doing anything either. I hope this is not a complicated problem to solve T.T

Comment: Do you want random chunks from your array ?

Comment: Do you also need `setInterval`? Do you want to change the image without click each 5 seconds?

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut I want to display random images every time the user clicks the hole. Out of 25 items.

Comment: @AliSheikhpour I do need that because have a 3-2-1 counter before the users are allowed to click the hole.

Comment: Good work on the graphic.

Comment: @JosephDoggie Why thank you~!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be worthwhile restructuring your code slightly. It looks like you are grouping your items.

```
var items = [{
    image: "imgs/garbagebag.svg",
    type: "paper"
}, {
    image: "imgs/straw.svg",
    type: "paper"
},
...]
```

This gives you a lot more flexibility in the meta data behind each item.

Then you need to add the events

```
var hole = document.getElementById("hole");

function showItem(item) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.setAttribute("src", item.image);
    // store type as data attribute so we can access it later
    img.setAttribute("data-type", item.type);
    if (hole.childNodes[0]) {
        hole.removeChild(hole.childNodes[0]);
    }
    hole.appendChild(img);
}

function showRandomItem() {
    var item = items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)];
    showItem(item);
}

hole.addEventListener("click", function() {
    showRandomItem();
});
```

Here is a working version of this code on JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/nxc5zpen/

It looks like the issues you might be having are due to SVG scaling. Here is a working JSFiddle with SVGs.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lhot76gm/1/

And here is another version using background images for the hole.

https://jsfiddle.net/j6373mvv/1/

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for reconstructing my code to the stage where it is applicable. So I have a few questions after I reconstructed in the same way as you. 1. When you set an attribute, isn't "variable image" the same as "item.image" and you still used "item.image" 2. I get an error for removeChild part, saying play.js:147 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
    at showItem 
    at showRandomItem 
    at HTMLImageElement.<anonymous>  But when I remove it, I get no errors but images still does not show.

Comment: Good spot, I've updated the example to remove the redundant code. Removing the existing item might need to be in an additional check (I'm not sure how it currently works for you). If you inspect the page does the HTML change? I will make a JSFiddle and update my answer.

Comment: Okay! After applying your change, I get no errors. Unfortunately, images still don't show and when I console.log an array [items] inside addeventListenser, I do not see the items? Do I need to parse or stringify it or something? Thank you again!

Comment: No I don't think so, check the JSFiddle for a working example. Would you be able to provide an example of it not working? It's hard to know the exact issue.

Comment: Okay, I will. Let me reply to you this evening. I have other errands to take care of. Thank you!

Comment: Okay I found a funny glitch...Apparently it is working but for some reason, the images that are created have no pixels thus, not showing in the hole. I tried to assign "img" to className and increase z-index or adjust width and height but that is not doing anything...I uploaded the example.

Comment: Based on the screenshot you posted it's because your hole is an image. Would you be able to change it to a div, with background image? Then we can overlay the images in the div? I've added a JSFiddle example

Comment: Interesting...so because we are appending and removing images, the hole image is impacting images in an array? It is working now. I can not thank you enough for all your help. Thank you so much! Can I bother you with one more question? So when I exported, I did not check the size of each svg, thus making them look unbalanced in terms of size. If I were to change the width of a certain object (let's say "banana"), how should I approach this method? or would it be easier to resize them in illustrator?

Comment: Easier to resize in illustrator. Web browsers will keep the scale of SVGs even if you change the width and height so it can't easily be changed that way. :)

Comment: Wow such a fast reply. Okay, I will do that. So is there a way to target certain items in the array? Because I am going to create an interaction with drag and drop method with items and bins...(drag the item into the bin). Sorry for keep asking questions!

Comment: You might be able to add another property to each object in the array and add an id property. Then, much like type, add a data-id attribute. You'd be able to use this on drag and drop to work out exactly which one was selected etc...

Comment: Hi, sorry for a late reply. I have been pondering and trying different methods such as assigning an id to the random element by "img.setAttribute("id",item.type);" But the problem I having is I do not know how to call that id. For example, instead of drag and drop, I decide to make the item disappear when one of the bins is clicked. so for example, score = 0; paperBin.addEventListener("click",function(){
    if ( the item in the hole is paper id) { remove the item and score++;}
}); I appreciate if you can give me a tip and thank you as always.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to get item from an array

```
var randItem = items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];
```

Comment: Thank you. I think I wrote the same thing?

Comment: @YongJunJung Yea, just saw it now. Perhaps we posted at the same time. :) :D